# Sort a table with rowspan

Tags: jquery, datatables, tablesorter

I'm French so, please, don't be afraid by my sentences mistakes.

I'm trying to sort a tab which contains cells with rowspan :

But with datatables or tablesorter, I don't know if it is possible. Do you know how I can do this with tablesorter ou datatables? Do you know an other plugin which can do this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up modifying this implementation:

https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/806

```
  $('#results-table').bind("sortEnd updateComplete",function(e, table) {
    $(table).find("[data-row]").each(function(idx, parent){
        var $parent = $(parent);
        var $rows = $(table).find('[data-parent="'+$parent.data('row')+'"]');

        $rows.after($parent);
        $rows.show();
    });
});
```

I made the `data-parent` attribute the parent tr's data attr. Then the child rows I gave the `data-row` attr.

This preserves order within the groups and only groups by the firstmost row in the group.

See this fiddle for example:
http://jsfiddle.net/djhqmt92/

Comment: Best answer.  Solved my problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> **"jQuery tablesorter - rowspan in headers causes odd behavior"**

I figured out the problem myself when i face it with tablesorter , ofcourse by googling.
and now it's working perfectly.

```
        var headers = {};
headers[0]={ sorter: false };
var tds={}
  $('table').tablesorter({
    headers: headers
  });
    $("table").bind("sortStart",function() { 
        $('table tbody tr:first td').each(function(i,h){
            if (this.rowSpan>1) { 
                $(this).css('background','#CCC');
                headers[i] = { sorter: false }; 
                tds[i]=h;
                h.remove()
            }
          });
    }).bind("sortEnd",function() { 
        $.each(tds,function(i,td){
            $('table tbody tr:first td:eq('+(i-1)+')').after(td);
        });
        $('table tbody tr').each(function(i,tr){
            $('td:first',tr).html(i+1);
        });
    });
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ajumt/8Ynnq/)

Answer (score 0):

To add to Aju M T's answer, I had to do a table, where rowspan is on the first TD, so this fix won't work on table like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/S4872/

It helped to add a dummy TD in front of the table and add CSS

```
dummy-tab {
   display: none;
}
```

like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/S4872/2/